# Ionic ios app can't reach API with livereload

Tags: ionic-framework, cors

Using `ionic emulate ios`, is able to reach the API on my local machine just fine. However, `ionic emulate ios -l -c`, the app's API requests can only reach the server in the form of preflight requests:

```
OPTIONS /api/user/get/profile_mob 200 1.68 ms
```

`ionic.project` uses a proxy:

```
"proxies": [
    {
      "path": "/api",
      "proxyUrl": "https://dev.app.com/api"
    }
 ]
```

`nginx.conf` below:

```
location /api {
  add_header              'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
  add_header              'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, PATCH, DELETE';
  add_header              'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' 'true';
  add_header              'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'X-Requested-With,content-type';
  proxy_redirect          off;
  proxy_http_version      1.1;
  proxy_set_header        Host $http_host;
  proxy_set_header        X-Scheme $scheme;
  proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP $remote_addr;

  proxy_set_header        Upgrade     $http_upgrade;
  proxy_set_header        Connection  "upgrade";

  proxy_hide_header       X-Powered-By;
  proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
  proxy_pass              http://localhost:3003;
}
```

From my readings, configuring the proxy and adding proxy should have fixed the problem. What else can I try? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I had the same problem, You need to add the cordova whitelist plugin.

Answer (score 0):

as u have not mention,what plugins are been used..!
may be this could help u..!

1:  Add this plugin

```
cordova add plugin cordova-plugin-whitelist
```

2: check if `<access origin="*" />` is added in config.xml

3: Add the CSP for ' Enable all requests, inline styles, and eval()' to in index.html as shown in [here](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-whitelist#content-security-policy)

and for more see [this](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/rest-api-call-not-working-on-android-device/23418/6)..and [that](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/ionic-angular-http-post-results-in-a-404-but-only-on-an-android-phone-not-on-an-iphone-or-in-the-browser/28999/14)..

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution for us, we have an api that validates with cors the origins, it only admits request from localhost or 127.0.0.1, I had used the proxy approach but not works and then with --address param it works ok with live reload on device and emulador, we have two nom tasks, I hope this help:

```
"emulate:ios:debug": "ionic emulate ios --consolelogs --livereload --debug --address 127.0.0.1 --target=\"iPhone-6s\""

"device:ios:debug": "ionic prepare ios --device && ionic run ios --consolelogs --livereload --debug --address 127.0.0.1"
```

http://ionicframework.com/docs/cli/test.html